# freemarker and spring security taglib looking fo a list of functions

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, template-engine, freemarker

hi i'm working with a apring mvc project and i'm using freemarker as my template engine, i added spring secuirty to my pages like this

```
<#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />
```

and i put this tag in the content that i want to be visible to a specific user

```
<@security.authorize  ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
  <div><h1>Hello ADMIN</h1></div>
</@security.authorize>

<@security.authorize  ifAnyGranted="ROLE_USER">
  <div><h1>Hello USER</h1></div>
</@security.authorize>
```

my question is where i can find the list of functions like `ifAnyGranted` is there another functions besides this one?, this functions are for freemarker or spring security taglibs? because i'm looking the spring security taglib documentation and i cant find this functions they use functions like this `access="hasRole('guest')` and if i try that in my page it dont work, where can i find the functions like `ifAnyGranted` or anyother similar what is the name of this library that i'm using, i try searching in google freemarker and spring security and cant find to much info

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#taglibs

Comment: i use CRTL+F in that link and i couldnt find any `ifAnyGranted` or any similar function

Comment: That link is for JSP. This question is about Freemarker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret the documentation correct, some functions/properties are not listed because they are legacy options from Spring Security 2.0 and use of them is discouraged. You can write them as security expressions instead.

Old way:

```
<@security.authorize  ifAnyGranted="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN">
```

New way:

```
<@security.authorize  access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
```

If you still you want to use the old way, the [authz package](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/taglibs/authz/package-summary.html) gives you available properties.

Comment: it gives me this error when i try to use hasRole ` Lexical error: encountered <EOF> after "\"hasRole(\'ROLE_ADMIN\')>\r\n    <div><h1>Hello ADMIN</h1></div>\r\n  </@security.authorize>\r\n  \r\n</@layout.myLayout>".]`

Comment: @stackUser2000 Looks like a freemarker syntax error. Missing a `"`?